# Putting Curly braces into javascript if's without curly braces?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, curly-braces

What I want:
Transforming this: 

`if(a == b)
//statement`

into:

`if(a == b)
{ //statement }`

Simply put: I want my single line if's to have their braces once again, and I need some program or plugin or some code, that would run over my code, and transform it to one with braces on every if.

How?

Thanks in advance,
Danny.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://mykzilla.blogspot.com/2007/10/automated-js-code-rewriting.html

Comment: Sorry I have to ask...why?? (please don't say jslint)

Comment: @PW Oh god.......really though, without context, I don't think that's a safe recommendation. It could break his codes functionality.

Comment: Oh well in that case perhaps we should "consider" not randomly bringing up jslint and jquery in every single javascript question. alksdjalksdjaslk. K I'm done raging...

Answer (score 1):

In general, doing this yourself (as code) is a pretty tough task - basically, you would need to correctly parse JavaScript's grammar.

You may be able to write some regexes to do it in very specifically formatted cases (e.g. when your statement is 100% on the same line as the `if` or 100% on the line followwing the `if`; and the `if` itself is the first non-whitespace in the line.